# How to make a modular partial views with AST.NET core maintaining the performance?

Tags: c#, css, performance, .net-core, partial-views

I want to be able to reuse parts of my views, like buttons, forms, things like that.

In my vision this avoid two things:

1. The needy of review an entire `CSS` to reuse that without an extra `CSS` codes that I'm not going to use.
2. Conflits of `CSS` codes if I just reuse and input my codes (beeing necessary the review again)

I already started to do this with [Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial), but I would need to define a style for each component, and with that my performance would get lower, according to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/seven-mistakes-that-make-websites-slow/), with this item, because of the number of HTTP Requests to fetch each `CSS` file:

> 1. Too Many HTTP Requests
>      This is the single biggest contributor to performance problems in most web pages.

Conclusion:

1. I'm developing Views
2. I want to reuse pieces of codes (the HTML with CSS)
3. I tried Partial Views, but there are the problems about including many CSS files

Is there a way to be able to use components, reuse the `CSS` code with that and avoid this problems of performance?

Or even, a way to improve my situation in other way that I'm not seeing how?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of CSS `@import` here?  Views are different than CSS files and your question is not fully clear your intent here. PartialViews are totally different than css files. CSS files are typically referenced in a Layout file.

Comment: OR perhaps put something in your build process to combine them?  Several options there.

Comment: Sorry, I made a section called conclusion, with the points you said.

Comment: Look a this answer for some insight here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69541  More general than MVC specific but still applies